# Please tell my the description of the exception is not appearing

Tags: java, exception

```
package javaapplication16;

class ExceptionoftheGods extends Exception {

    double b;

    ExceptionoftheGods (String msg){
    }

}

class mak {

    static void compute(int a) throws ExceptionoftheGods {
        System.out.println("Called Compute(" + a + ")");
        if(a > 7) {
            throw new ExceptionoftheGods("Dog");
        }
        System.out.println("Normal Exit");
    }    


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            compute(1);
            compute(9);
        } catch(ExceptionoftheGods e) {
            System.out.println(" Caught " + e);
        }
    }

}
```

OUTPUT

```
run:
Called Compute(1)
Normal Exit
Called Compute(9)
 Caught javaapplication16.ExceptionoftheGods
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ExceptionoftheGods(String msg) {
    super(msg); // missing
}
```

Comment: Hey, then ehat does e.getmessage specifically does?

Comment: @Abhay Saini: `String msg = e.getMessage()`. it enables to get the message description.

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke the base exception constructor in your subclass's constructor, otherwise the message won't actually be set:

```
ExceptionoftheGods(String msg) {
    super(msg);
}
```

Also, you are printing the exception object itself, not the exception's message. If you wanted to print just the message you need to directly call `getMessage()`, otherwise you get both the exception's type and the description.

Change

```
System.out.println(" Caught " + e);
```

to

```
System.out.println(" Caught " + e.getMessage());
```

Comment: But after doing that, the output comes

Comment: I updated my answer to explain printing the object versus printing `getMessage()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a new method, you must define all of its functionality. If you want it to work as the parent class method, then you must call `super`

Either you do not define the constructor (and leave only the default -empty- constructor available), or you modify your constructor.

```
ExceptionoftheGods (String msg){
  super(msg);
}
```

Comment: The constructors of the superclass will *not* be available if you do not define any constructors. Constructors are not inherited.

Comment: ok, then what's the difference between outputting e and e.getmessage? In one comes Caught Dog,  and in other comes description of the exception along with String msg?

Comment: @Abhay Saini: When you do System.out.println(e) (or even, "" + e), the JVM calls e.toString() (for all objects, not only Exception). So it is the implementation of toString() what will decide what to show. The toString() of Exception will look for the value that you passed in its constructor to print it, so you need either to do super(msg), or to redefine toString() to suit your nees.

Comment: @Thilo: My mistake, I was thinking of the default constructor. Corrected, thanks.

Comment: @Abhay Saini: The same applies to getMessage(). As you have not implemented it in your class, it will use super.getMessage() that looks for that field.